# pandas groupby, cannot apply iloc to grouped objects

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Apologies if my question has been answered before, or the answer is obvious.

Let's say that in my dataset there are two tasks, 20 different trials each. Now I would like to select only last 6 seconds of each trial for further analysis.

The dataset looks sort of like this (+more columns). This sample covers all 20 trials of one task. Index values are as in the full dataset, time is given in unix timestamps (ms).

```
index   time                x           y          Trial_Id
13512   1519227368636.0000  1022.0000   602.0000    1
13513   1519227368683.0000  1019.0000   697.0000    1
13514   1519227368728.0000  966.0000    530.0000    1
13515   1519227368752.0000  961.0000    576.0000    1
13516   1519227368806.0000  1120.0000   631.0000    1
...
17076   1519227518503.0000  804.0000    694.0000    20
17077   1519227518549.0000  789.0000    738.0000    20
17078   1519227518596.0000  809.0000    747.0000    20
17079   1519227518678.0000  806.0000    735.0000    20
17080   1519227518713.0000  823.0000    605.0000    20
```

On the level of single trial iloc does the job. However, when I try to apply iloc on the data grouped by trial_Id, I get the error:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be
>   hashed.

The code I use:

a function to preserve the last 6 seconds

> def img_trial(data, start):
>       data1 = data.iloc[start:-1,:]
>       return data1

a function application on data grouped by trial

> data.groupby(['Trial_Nr']).apply(img_trial(data, 80))

Can you please give me a hint on what's wrong? I'm quite a pandas-newbie.
Sorry if my question is not clear enough (that's the first post of a long time lurker).

Best regards,

Nat

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: If your time is to second resolution then you could do something like: `df.sort_values('time_column').groupby('Trial_Nr').tail(6)` - but it's hard to say until you include the necessary information in the post as per @jezrael's comment...

Comment: thanks for the hints! I hope that the last edit clarifies my question a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `max` value per group of `datetime`:

```
print (df)
    index                time       x      y  Trial_Id
8   13515  1519227361052.0000   961.0  576.0         1
7   13514  1519227362028.0000   966.0  530.0         1
5   13512  1519227363636.0000  1022.0  602.0         1
4   13516  1519227364806.0000  1120.0  631.0         1
3   13515  1519227365752.0000   961.0  576.0         1
2   13514  1519227366728.0000   966.0  530.0         1
1   13513  1519227367683.0000  1019.0  697.0         1
9   13516  1519227368906.0000  1120.0  631.0         1
6   13513  1519227369283.0000  1019.0  697.0         1
0   13512  1519227369836.0000  1022.0  602.0         1
10  17076  1519227518503.0000   804.0  694.0        20
11  17077  1519227518549.0000   789.0  738.0        20
12  17078  1519227518596.0000   809.0  747.0        20
13  17079  1519227518678.0000   806.0  735.0        20
14  17080  1519227518713.0000   823.0  605.0        20
```

---

```
#convert column time to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(float), unit='ms')

#get max date per group
max_per_group = df.groupby('Trial_Id')['time'].transform('max') 
#subtract 6 seconds
diff_6_sec = max_per_group - pd.Timedelta(6, unit='s')
#filter
df = df[diff_6_sec < df['time']]
print (df)
    index                    time       x      y  Trial_Id
4   13516 2018-02-21 15:36:04.806  1120.0  631.0         1
3   13515 2018-02-21 15:36:05.752   961.0  576.0         1
2   13514 2018-02-21 15:36:06.728   966.0  530.0         1
1   13513 2018-02-21 15:36:07.683  1019.0  697.0         1
9   13516 2018-02-21 15:36:08.906  1120.0  631.0         1
6   13513 2018-02-21 15:36:09.283  1019.0  697.0         1
0   13512 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836  1022.0  602.0         1
10  17076 2018-02-21 15:38:38.503   804.0  694.0        20
11  17077 2018-02-21 15:38:38.549   789.0  738.0        20
12  17078 2018-02-21 15:38:38.596   809.0  747.0        20
13  17079 2018-02-21 15:38:38.678   806.0  735.0        20
14  17080 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713   823.0  605.0        20
```

For better understanding is possible concat all together for check:

```
print (pd.concat([df['time'], max_per_group, diff_6_sec], 
                 axis=1, 
                 keys=('orig', 'max', 'sub_6s')))

                      orig                     max                  sub_6s
8  2018-02-21 15:36:01.052 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
7  2018-02-21 15:36:02.028 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
5  2018-02-21 15:36:03.636 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
4  2018-02-21 15:36:04.806 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
3  2018-02-21 15:36:05.752 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
2  2018-02-21 15:36:06.728 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
1  2018-02-21 15:36:07.683 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
9  2018-02-21 15:36:08.906 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
6  2018-02-21 15:36:09.283 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
0  2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:09.836 2018-02-21 15:36:03.836
10 2018-02-21 15:38:38.503 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713 2018-02-21 15:38:32.713
11 2018-02-21 15:38:38.549 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713 2018-02-21 15:38:32.713
12 2018-02-21 15:38:38.596 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713 2018-02-21 15:38:32.713
13 2018-02-21 15:38:38.678 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713 2018-02-21 15:38:32.713
14 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713 2018-02-21 15:38:38.713 2018-02-21 15:38:32.713
```

Comment: Can you however please elaborate on 'lambda x: x.max() - pd.Timedelta(6, unit='s')'? you shift the max value by 6 seconds down?
And then: df = df[s < df['time']]
this removes all datetimes that are larger than shifted datetimes in the series?

I triple checked and it does the job but I am still confused as to how. Sorry if this is obvious

Comment: @user396156 - sure, also I have idea for better answer.